# Gracefully and Patiently reboot a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application that performs many automatic tasks, in chain and sometimes I break the chain by performing a reboot and need to mannually fix the mess.

Is there any way to check if there are running processes called by controllers / models and only perform the reboot after those are finished?

Thanks

Comment: This is quite vague, which i think is why you're being marked down, but `ps ax | grep <processname>` is a way to see if a process is running, and you can also test for the existence of pid files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python you can use job queue like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to do this.

You can follow bellow tutorial and add a task to job queue and use the provided back-end to get the status and task a wait for it to be done.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

First define a task using job queue

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Then run the celery worker:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

Now you can run the function using the job queue:

```
>>> from tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(4, 4)
```

You can wait for the result by running below command:

```
>>> result.wait()
```